# Perform function on a value in column with other parameters and then carry forward

Tags: pandas

[Edit]: to better reflect complexity of situation.

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 'B': [2,6,4,0,2,0,0,0], 'C': [3,4,4,2,6,4,6,2], 'D': [4,4,2,2,2,4,4,8]})
```

resulting in:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   3   4
1   1   6   4   4
2   1   4   4   2
3   1   0   2   2
4   1   2   6   2
5   1   0   4   4
6   1   0   6   4
7   1   0   2   8
```

My formula essentially is

```
df['A'] = ((df['A'] * df['B']) + (df['C'] * df['D'])) / (df['B'] + df['D'])
```

With df['A'] being replaced and used for the next row's calculations, and so on down the column.

Resultant DF looks like this:

```
    A    B  C   D
0   2.3  2  3   4
1   3.0  6  4   4
2   3.3  4  4   2
3   2.0  0  2   2
4   4.0  2  6   2
5   4.0  0  4   4
6   6.0  0  6   4
7   2.0  0  2   8
```

My difficulty is how do I make the calculation with all these parameters, update A, and propagate it down for the next calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
df.loc[:,'A'] = ((df['A'] * df['B']) + (df['C'] * df['D'])) / (df['B'] + df['D'])
```

Not sure what you mean by propagation.